# Combining class and ID in your CSS selector, best practice?

Tags: css

When combining a class and ID in CSS is it better practice to use *.class#id* or *#id.class*? Does one have advantages over the other, or are they treated exactly the same by every browser? Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

They both point to the same element due to that `id` selector, so they work the same way.

As for advantages, I feel that `.class#id` is suited more for specific cases of a `.class` element (like a sticky post in a blog), and a `#id.class` is just an extension of the `#id` element's stylesheet.

I'm not sure if this is common practice, but I find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can find some useful information here:
[How to combine class and ID in CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028248/how-to-combine-class-and-id-in-css-selector)

Comment: So it looks like #id.class is the accepted usage. Strangely, both variations work in modern browsers.

Comment: I would say luckily both variantions work in modern browsers :)