# apply CSS style to particular elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with paragraphs inside:

```
<div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I want dynamically to apply a certain style to paragraphs inside this div. Is it possible to do that without handling each paragraph element, but just attach somehow style to div element and all inside paragraphs would be affected?

Maybe with jquery.

It sounds for me like dynamical change of the stylesheet, is it possbile?

---

The right recommendation in answer's comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using classes:

```
/* using CSS */
div p {
    color: #ff0000;
}

// using jQuery
$("div p").css({
    color : "#ff0000"
});
```

With classes for `<p>` elements:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <p class="mypar">...</p>
    <p class="mypar">...</p>
</div>

/* using CSS */
div p.mypar {
    color: #ff0000;
}

// using jQuery
$("div p.mypar").css({
    color : "#ff0000"
});
```

With classes for `<div>` element:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="mydiv">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

/* using CSS */
div.mydiv p {
    color: #ff0000;
}

// using jQuery
$("div.mydiv p").css({
    color : "#ff0000"
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to do it with jquery and css selector, but it will effect only existing paragraphs, and if I will dynamicly add them, new won't be affected - and I want them to be. It is possible with css stylesheet applied to the element, but is css stylesheet possible to change it dynamically?

Comment: CSS will work fine for dynamically added elements. JavaScript case should be run again to attach styles to the new elements.

Comment: So its not possible to do what I want? Change css style and automatically apply it all new added elements of the certain type?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: It is possible, but it's not usually required. Why can't you just use CSS to set the style in the first place, or run a `.css()` call whenever paragraphs are newly added?

Comment: 1) because styles is dynamical  2) I'm trying to find a quicker (in terms of execution time) way to do that .

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: Well, the quick way is just to append a `style` element, something like: `$('head').append('<style>/* new CSS here */</style>');`. For anything more complicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Comment: Ah, yes, that might work out, thanks. Mark as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS you can define a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

Building on that, you can dynamically add/remove a style class to your `div` and the style will apply to the children you specify in that selector.

Let's assume you want to apply this to a specific `div`, not any/every one. So give the target `div` an identifier:

```
<div id='foo'>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Adding a dynamic style with simple javascript:

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.className='dynamic_style'
```

The CSS (using [combined id and class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028260/127035) on a child selector):

```
div#foo.dynamic_style > p { /* your style definition*/ }
```

Comment: If i have to compose style during runtime? "font-size: 21px; margin: 12px", I don't have 'dynamic_style' defined in css file.

Comment: You don't *define* the style dynamically, you *apply* the style dynamically. So, define the style statically in your CSS. Apply the style dynamically by adding className to document element with Javascript.

Comment: Ok, thanks =) just in my case it's not possible to define style statically.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
div p {your style goes here}
```

jquery:

```
$('div p').css('property', 'value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the CSS dynamically for this example of yours in this way:

```
function applyCSS()
{
    $("div > p").css({
        "background": "#fff",
        "color": "#000"
    });
}
```

Or, when you wanna apply this when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    applyCSS();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the css dynamically would be as simple as changing the top level class name for example

```
<div id="toggleme" class="class1">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<a id="test">Test</a>
```

​

```
.class1 {
 background-color:#F00;
}

.class1 p {
    color:#00F;
}

.class2 {
    background-color:#00F;
}

.class2 p {
 color:#F00;
}​
```

then the jquery would be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        $('#toggleme').toggleClass('class1');
        $('#toggleme').toggleClass('class2');
    });
});​
```

Everything below the class will change to its new style :)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nS4VG/)