# When combining selectors does space means the same as no space?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In CSS combining selectors with space means [descendance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

But in another answer [How to combine class and ID in CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028248/how-to-combine-class-and-id-in-css-selector) I read, that similar syntax means coinciding selected markers in one tag.

Does CSS parser really distinguish space and no-space, or this is the same syntax which is just working in both cases?

Comment: I think you misunderstood that answer.

Comment: *"Does CSS parser really distinguish space and no-space"* Yes. *"When combining selectors does space means the same as no space?"* No.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, spaces are significant in CSS rules.

`#tag.flower` means an element with both `id="tag"` and `class="flower"`, where `#tag .flower` means an element with `class="flower"` inside of an element with `id="tag"`.

For instance:

`#tag.flower`

```
<div id="tag" class="flower"></div>
```

`#tag .flower`

```
<div id="tag">
    <div class="flower"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist Boaz - didn't know the hashes caused wonky formatting!

Comment: No problem. Also note how backsticks are used to format inline code snippets. See [StackOveflow - Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 5):

A space in  CSS selectors, like:

```
.foo .bar {...
```

indicated a [descendant element](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/descendant). This would target the inner div with class "bar" for example,

```
<div class="foo">foo
    <div class="bar">bar</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q67VB/)**

Removing the space means that the you are selecting an element has has both classes, like:

```
.foo.bar {...
```

Which would target the div with both classes foo and bar in this example:

```
<div class="foo">foo
    <div class="foo bar">foo and bar</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q67VB/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

To select `.bee` which is direct descendant of `.aye`:

> .aye > .bee {...}

To select element `.aye` and element `.bee`:

> .aye, .bee {...}

To select `.bee` which is just a descendant of `.aye` (not necessarily direct descendant):

> .aye .bee {...}

To select an element that is both `.aye` and `.bee`:

> .aye.bee {...}

Comment: Thx for the cleanup Boaz, my English is a bit redundant :)