# Why doesn't "input .foo" (with a space) CSS style work but "input.foo" (no space) does?

Tags: css

Can anyone explain why the following CSS style works:

```
input.foo {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But the following one doesn't:

```
input .foo {
    background-color: red;
}
```

All I did was add a space after `input`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When combining selectors does space means the same as no space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175379/when-combining-selectors-does-space-means-the-same-as-no-space)

Comment: Because these two selectors mean different things. Basic CSS 101: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input.foo` means an `input` with a class of `foo`.

`input .foo` means elements with a class of `foo` contained in an `input` element.

These are fundamentally different.

E.g.

`label.foo` targets this `label` element:

```
<label class="foo"></label>
```

But `label .foo` will target the `span` in this:

```
<label>
    <span class="foo">
</label>
```

Read more on CSS Selectors:
*CSS 2.1*: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html
*CSS 3*: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select an `input` tag with a class of `.foo`. The second one selects an element within `input` with a class of `.foo`.

The first one means selecting this type of element:

```
<input class="foo" />
```

The second means:

```
<input>
    <div class="foo" />
</input>
```

Which would be invalid in HTML, but that's beside the point.