# Where am I going wrong with the CSS selector?

Tags: css

I've read [the question about combining the class and ID in the CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028248/how-to-combine-class-and-id-in-css-selector) but it's not working for me and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

I have the following set of divs:

```
<div id="maincontent" class="2col clearfix">
    <div id="leftcolumn">content</div>
</div>
```

and the following in my css:

```
#maincontent.2col {
    width: 840px;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

#maincontent.2col #leftcolumn   {
    float: left;
    width: 490px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    text-align: left;
}
```

However, when I use firebug, nothing is happening to the `#leftcolumn` div.

If I remove the `.2col` from both it works as I would expect it to, but I'd like to have the 2col class in there as I'm going to be having a 3 column layout and I don't want to have more than one stylesheet. Any thoughts?

**Edit**: Apologies, that's not a misspelling in my HTML, that's a misspelling when trying to write it out here.

Comment: I'm going to propose that this gets reopened. I would say that some people (including some front-end people that I asked this same question to) aren't aware that you can't have a CSS class starting with a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your classes cannot begin with a number.

**CSS 2.1:**

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

**CSS 3:**

> In CSS3, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors (see [SELECT] [or is this still true])) can contain only the
>   characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters 161 and higher, plus
>   the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**
>   or a hyphen followed by a digit. They can also contain escaped
>   characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next
>   item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?"
>   or "B\26 W\3F". (See [UNICODE310] and [ISO10646].)

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#characters,  and also [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

Answer (score 3):

You have misspelled the class attribute

```
<div id="maincontent" class="2col clearfix">
   <div id="leftcolumn">content</div>
</div>

#maincontent.2col {
width: 840px;
margin: 0px auto; 
text-align: center;
}

#maincontent.2col #leftcolumn   {
float: left;
width: 490px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
/*border: 1px solid #000;*/
text-align: left;
}
```

And you can't start a class name with a number in CSS - your selector won't work until you change that.

From the 2.1 Spec:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Comment: As I posted above, that was a typo in my question

Comment: You can't start a class name with a number in CSS - thats the problem

Answer (score -1):

The `class` attribute is misspelled

Comment: The OP updated his question and said that he made a typo.