# Need to set width depends upon its content

Tags: html, css

I need to set width for div depends upon its content..
Below is my HTML flow.

Flow 1:

```
<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content skip-active">
<div class="minicart-wrapper">
<p class="block-subtitle"></p>
<p class="empty">You have no items in your shopping cart.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Flow 2:

```
<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content skip-active">
<div class="minicart-wrapper">
<p class="block-subtitle"></p>
<div>
<div id="minicart-widgets"> </div>
<div class="block-content"></div>
<div class="minicart-actions"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have two HTML flows explained above..
What i need is to set

> width as 220px and 300px

for

> `<div id="header-cart">`

.

When there is an occurance of `<p class="empty"> in <div id="header-cart">`

`<div id="header-cart">` should be in

> width 220px

.

and if not it should be in 300px.

I dont know how to set flow for this cascade.

Can any one help me?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: U may use jquery or js to check whether class is empty

Comment: There are no parent selectors in CSS, not even in CSS3. So it's not possible to do by only html and css

Comment: Yes then without JS it is not possible because you are asking to change width of parent class based on child .

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript for this.

```
if(document.querySelectorAll("div#header-cart p.empty").length==0){

   document.getElementById('header-cart').style.width="300px";

}else{

   document.getElementById('header-cart').style.width="220px";

}
```

Comment: May be OP forgot to tag Javascript.

Comment: nopes i need to do it only in css?? is there any possible to do it without using js??

Comment: Add it as comment then!!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your above code i feel there is no need to go for any script for this. You can acheive the same with existing css classes.

**Flow 1:**

Default class is applying. so, give the base width for this class.

```
.skip-content { width: 220px; }
```

**Flow 2:**

Active class is applying. So, give the active class width for this class.

```
.skip-active { width: 300px; } // This will be applied in active time.
```

Comment: No brother, .skip-content and .skip-active will always occur on the both flows.

Answer (score 1):

i think this can be done by stylign inline

```
<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content" style="width:220px;">
<div class="minicart-wrapper">
<p class="block-subtitle"></p>
<p class="empty">You have no items in your shopping cart.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content skip-active" style="width:300px;">
<div class="minicart-wrapper">
<p class="block-subtitle"></p>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="minicart-widgets"> </div>
<div class="block-content"></div>
<div class="minicart-actions"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

or make a another div for flow 1 and 2 like this

```
<div id="flow1">
<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content">
<div class="minicart-wrapper">
<p class="block-subtitle"></p>
<p class="empty">You have no items in your shopping cart.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="flow2">
<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content skip-active">
<div class="minicart-wrapper">
<p class="block-subtitle"></p>
<div>
<div id="minicart-widgets"> </div>
<div class="block-content"></div>
<div class="minicart-actions"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#flow1 {width:220px;}
#flow2 {width:300px;}
```

sample - http://jsfiddle.net/wd54paav/

Comment: No brother, these flows should comes in dynamic. we cant able set it as predefined. The only source to analyze this function is through <p class="empty">. No other options are available.

Comment: try using this css div#header-cart .block block-cart skip-content {width:220px;} div#header-cart .block block-cart skip-content skip-active {width:300px;} i think this is possible by combining the id with the class 

reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028248/how-to-combine-class-and-id-in-css-selector