# CSS reference an ID that is inside a container?

Tags: css, tags

I want to reference one of the images in my container by id 'reg' without changing the properties of the others, how would I do that?

```html
<div class="two_third lastcolumn">
    <div class="container clients">                   
        <div class="one_sixth"><a href="userProfile.php"><img src="../../images/reg.png" alt="" id="reg"/></a></div>
        <div class="one_sixth"><a href="../../community/feedback.php"><img src="../../images/feedback.png" alt=""/></a></div>
        <div class="one_sixth"><a href="../../resources/donation.php"><img src="../../images/donate.png" alt=""/></a></div>
        <div class="one_sixth"><a href="userProfile.php"><img src="../../images/oneyear.png" alt=""/></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My guess would be something like

```css
.clients img #reg {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `img #reg` is looking for an element with the id `#reg` that is a child of an `img` element - which of course is impossible. Just do `#reg`. Only one element on the page can have that Id, so you don't need to preface it with other selectors

Comment: `.clients img#reg`, `.clients #reg` or `#reg` is fine. Noted these CSS selectors has different meanings, but they work the same.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors refer to this

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use all those selectors.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="clients">                   
                <div><a href="#"><img src="a.png.png" id="small" alt=""/></a></div>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="b.png.png" alt=""/></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
img {
    width: 200;
    height: 200;
}
#small {
    width: 150;
    height: 150;
}
```

If you need to specify further, instead of assigning the class "clients" to the div, apply it to each img like this, with no spaces.
Reference: [How to combine class and ID in CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028248/how-to-combine-class-and-id-in-css-selector)

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div><a href="#"><img src="a.png.png" alt=""/></a></div> 
            <div class="clients">                   
                <div><a href="#"><img src="a.png.png" class="clients" id="small" alt=""/></a></div>
                <div><a href="#"><img src="b.png.png" class="clients" alt=""/></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
img {
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
}
img.clients {
    width: 200;
    height: 200;
}
img.clients#small {
    width: 150;
    height: 150;
}
```

Comment: OP might need them for other styling purposes