# CSS selector Goodreads user rating

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

Website: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27841061-nevernight
Goal: To extract individual user ratings

When I inspect the user rating, I see this.

```
<span class="staticStars notranslate" title="did not like it">
```

If I can extract the title I can map the ratings.

```
rate_map = {'did not like it': 1,
'it was ok': 2,
'liked it': 3,
'really liked it': 4,
'it was amazing': 5}

url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27841061-nevernight'
gr_list <- read_html(url)
gr_list %>%  html_node('.staticStars .notranslate') %>%  
  html_attr('title')
```

The result I am getting for the code is "NA".

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450981/rvest-scrape-2-classes-in-1-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css selector `.staticStars .notranslate` means you are looking for a node with a class `notranslate` nested in a node with a class `staticStars`. That is, it would match something like this

```
<span class="staticStars"><span class="notranslate">foo</span></span>
```

If you want to to match a node that has both classes, you need to make sure there is no space between the selectors. You can do

```
url <- 'https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27841061-nevernight'
gr_list <- read_html(url)
gr_list %>%  html_nodes('.staticStars.notranslate') %>% 
  html_attr('title')

#  [1] NA                NA                "did not like it"
#  [4] "did not like it" "it was amazing"  "it was amazing" 
#  [7] "it was amazing"  "it was amazing"  "it was amazing" 
# [10] "did not like it" "it was amazing"  "really liked it"
# [13] "did not like it" "it was amazing"  "it was amazing" 
# [16] "it was amazing"  "did not like it" "it was amazing" 
# [19] "it was amazing"  "it was amazing"  "it was amazing" 
# [22] "it was amazing"  "it was amazing"  "it was amazing" 
# [25] "it was amazing"  "it was amazing"  "it was amazing" 
# [28] "it was amazing"  "it was amazing"  "liked it"
```

Comment: That was a mistake on my end. The output is still NA

Comment: Well, the first node doesn't have a title. If you change `html_node` to `html_nodes` you'll get all the nodes and you'll see that most have a title.