# Changing css style with document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css, cssom

In CSS I am trying to assign multiple elements ids to a class and change their display property to "none" using a javascript with both document.getElementsByClassName and style.display.
In css I used  #content.myClass which I found in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028248/how-to-combine-class-and-id-in-css-selector?rq=1).

I am doing this to reduce the unique selectors and keep my code efficient.

html:

```
  <p id="toy-pictures-latest" class="panel">Latest Toy Pictures</p><br>
         <p id="toy-pictures-greatest" class="panel">Greatest Toy Pictures</p>
```

css:

```
#toy-pictures-latest.panel{
    display: inline;
}

#toy-pictures-greatest.panel{
        display: inline;
}
```

js:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('panel').style.display = "none";
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/VwaxRVv)

It doesn't appear to be making the text vanish as expected. How should I approach this?
No jQuery, please.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element. If you want the first one use `getElementsByClassName('panel')[0]` or `document.querySelector('.panel')`

Comment: document.querySelector('.panel').style.display = "none";  makes the first line vanish but not the second.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/yLOjwwx)

Comment: Then you need to loop over the collection and modify each instance you want. querySelector only finds first match in page

Comment: var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel'), i;

for (i = 0; i < panels.length; ++i) {
  panels[i].style.display = "none";
}